# WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync throws exception

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

My code uses :

```
WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync( 
                                        WebAuthenticationOptions.None, 
                                        StartUri, 
                                        EndUri);
```

just like the [Microsoft Web authentication broker sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

It used to work on my desktop and on my tablet (Surface) but now it is not working on my desktop. It throws exception

```
The process terminated unexpectedly. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007042B)
```

It is working on the tablet and on different windows-8 desktop.

Any suggestion what can cause this exception?

Comment: It seems that WebAuthenticationBroker only works in WinRT.

Comment: The problem could be that it only works on the UI thread.

Comment: If you haven't done it already, there is a specific event log for WebAutheticationBroker. See this... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj658959(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: could this possibly be a corrupt user profile..? is there a way for you to narrow it down , delete that user profile again and then retry it..? also what does the result of the expected URI look like..?if you use this (WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri() returns the ms-app:// uri)..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that the WebAuthBroker needs to be invoke on the UI Thread since it is trying to change something to your UI in the way of showing you the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync kicks off AuthHost.exe process as a child of the app process, and the HRESULT returned by the exception indicates that AuthHost.exe failed unexpectedly. When launched, AuthHost tries to purge cookies, content and history from non sso containers, and if it fails, it backs off. On the other side, a Windows App runs in a sandbox with a set of permissions different from a desktop application. Thus Internet Explorer itself or a desktop application doing SSO might be able to work normally, but AuthHost will not be allowed to do required clean up on start. In my case, a user running the app was a part of the group that was granted full access to the folder, but the user itself did not have direct file access permissions. However, the group rights got stripped off in the app sandbox.
In a default set up, permissions are configured properly, and no such problems should arise. However, in come cases a user moves the Temporary Internet Files to a new location, which might have a slightly different set of file access permissions. The other response on this thread suggests that deleting and re-creating profile helps. This operation resets Temporary Internet Files settings in the Internet Explorer to default, indirectly supporting my suggestion.